# Scroll only current line when truncating lines

Tags: scrolling, line-truncation

When using `(set-default 'truncate-lines t)`, and when moving to the end of the long line, is it possible to make Emacs scroll *only that line*, while the other lines stand still? `nano` does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs 26 has a new feature to horizontal scroll the current line when the variable `truncate-lines` is *also* non-nil. The variable to control that new feature is `auto-hscroll-mode` and the relevant portion from the doc-string reads:   "*... The value `'current-line` means the line displaying point in each window is automatically scrolled horizontally to make point visible.*"  The `auto-hscroll-mode` variable is *global*.  The variable `truncate-lines` is *buffer-local* when set.  My personal preference is to use `auto-hscroll-mode` on a *buffer-local* basis, which generally means that the major-mode must be activated in the buffer before setting these variables:

```lisp
(setq truncate-lines t)
(setq-local auto-hscroll-mode 'current-line)
```

As suggested in a comment by @Basil hereinbelow, it would behoove anyone who is interested in the horizontal scrolling feature to read the relevant portion from the Emacs manual:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Horizontal-Scrolling.html  [Inasmuch as Emacs 26 has not yet been officially released, it may be a few months before the on-line manual is updated with this particular new feature.]

In a comment by the O.P. underneath an alternative answer, there was a question about exclusions to a variable such as `truncate-lines`.  The way in which that particular variable is used does not contemplate exclusions.  The default value is `nil`.  One could change the default value to a non-nil value using `setq-default`, and override that setting on a buffer-local basis by using a major-mode hook to set the value to `nil` using `setq`.

Comment: I recommend linking to the manual node which describes all of this in more detail: [`(emacs) Horizontal Scrolling`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Horizontal-Scrolling.html); otherwise, +1.

Comment: (add-hook 'rmail-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                         (setq truncate-lines nil)))

Comment: @forthrin It's better not to quote `lambda`s: `(add-hook 'rmail-mode-hook (lambda () (setq truncate-lines nil)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Not with out-of-the-box Emacs, I believe. But maybe someone will kindly provide an answer (e.g. code) that does that.

My suggestion is to use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to request this as an enhancement (that command is also for enhancement requests).  Essentially, you want to be able to scroll a single line (or perhaps selected lines - the lines in the active region).  That might be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure when this was introduced as a *feature*, but I use it in my own setup:  `(setq-local auto-hscroll-mode 'current-line)` as a buffer-local setting:  "*... The value `‘current-line` means the line displaying point in each window is automatically scrolled horizontally to make point visible.*"

Comment: @lawlist: Please consider posting that as an answer. It sounds like an answer, or at least the makings of one (arbitrary line vs current line).

Comment: @lawlist: I couldn't get the `auto-hscroll-mode` thing to work (Emacs 25.3.1). PS! I'm not on the mailing list, but anyone please do post a feature request. Today's way of moving the entire buffer is not good.

Comment: @forthrin -- I haven't Googled and searched the latest new feature, but I would suggest just looking at your doc-string with `C-h f` or `M-x describe-variable`.  If it contains the exact quote mentioned in the first comment, then you are good to go.  If not, then you'll need Emacs 26 ... (not yet released to the general public, but is available to anyone who wants to build from source or download a nightly build from a variety of sources depending upon the OS).  [I added it manually to a pre-Emacs 25 release several months ago so that I can work on my own feature requests implemented in C...]

Comment: @lawlist: "Allow or disallow automatic horizontal scrolling of windows. If non-nil, windows are automatically scrolled horizontally to make point visible."

Comment: @forthrin -- then, there you have it.  It must be an Emacs 26 feature.  It is possible to patch an older version like I did, but you should use Emacs 26 if you would like to experiment with that new feature.  I think there is a release candidate available, but I have just used the Emacs 26 branch when communicating with the Emacs team to report bugs and seek guidance on the feature requests that I am working on (almost 2 years now ... and presently stuck ... :) ).

Comment: @lawlist: Hip hop hurray. `(setq-default truncate-lines t) (setq-default auto-hscroll-mode 'current-line)` does like `nano` in Emacs 26. You may post this as a answer. For bonus points, include how `truncate-lines` can be set for all modes except a list of certain modes. My native attempt `(setq truncate-lines '(not rmail-mode))` did not work.